# How can this PS1 variable be defined in single-quotes?

Tags: bash, syntax, quotes, ps1

The default `.bashrc` file for Debian-based systems sets `$PS1` like this:

```
PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

What confuses me is that `${debian_chroot}` part. According to [*StackOverflow: Difference between single and double quotes in bash*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/617937), if single-quotes are used when defining a string, characters such as `$` should be treated as a literal, rather than evaluate variables.

Doesn't this mean that Bash should *actually* print out `${debian_chroot:...`, and not the value of that variable? Or are there more syntax rules involved here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'd normally be right, except the value of `PS1` is expanded again at runtime as part of generating the prompt. This is specifically to allow expansions at runtime.

`PS1='$PWD: '` will expand `$PWD` when the prompt is shown, so that you always see the current directory.

`PS1="$PWD: "` will expand `$PWD` when the prompt is defined, so that you always see the directory you were in when you defined the prompt.

Comment: This is a bit of a side question, but how is the value of `PS1` "expanded again" when the prompt is shown? What lines of code would achieve this?

Comment: It's actually an entirely separate expansion mode ([source code](https://gitorious.org/bash/bash/source/81287b9114c72f606e3b9d52215da4ffef729045:y.tab.c#L7360)) that handles both backslash expansions and `$` type expansions (subject to the `promptvars` shell option). There's no good way of replicating the same functionality through bash code.

Answer (score 0):

It's often simpler to use `PROMPT_COMMAND` to set the value of `PS1` each time it is used. This way, you don't have to escape code in `PS1` itself.

```
make_prompt () {
    PS1="${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ "
}

PROMPT_COMMAND='make_prompt'
```